# Auto http authenticate traffic for a specific site with fiddler

Tags: http, authentication, web, header, fiddler

I am trying to figure out how I can get fiddler to autorespond or modify an http authenticate basic response so I don't have to keep entering in the username/password (I have over 200 sub-domains to try that require the credentials and I want to avoid doing each one).

I've tried adding in a autoresponder rule to identify the www-authenticate request with the value of Basic XXXXXXXXXXXX(encode string), but it doesn't seem to work when I am using a browser as a proxy set to fiddler (IE: localhost, port 8888)...

I have also tried adding into custom rules (and setting the "auto authenticate" flags): oSession["X-AutoAuth"] = "domain\username:password"; but that didn't work either.

Anyone know how I can do this? Did I miss something? Is there a better tool to handle this modification and how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `X-AutoAuth` flag won't help you because it only works for Digest, NTLM, and Negotiate authentication protocols, not Basic.

Using the AutoResponder won't help you, as your goal isn't to return a modified response to the client.

The proper way to do this is to have your FiddlerScript add the appropriate `Authorization: Basic xxxxxx` header to outbound requests.

Click `Rules` > `Customize Rules`. Scroll to `OnBeforeRequest`. Add something like:

```
if (oSession.hostname.EndsWith(".example.com"))
{
  oSession.oRequest["Authorization"] = "Basic xxxbase64encodedvaluexxx";
}
```

Save the script and all requests to anything ending with `.example.com` will get the credential header added automatically.