# No Alert Found using Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using ChromeDriver 2.14, selenium server 2.47.1 and Chrome 45. I am attempting to handle a basic authentication prompt. I have tried the following code to try and resolve this.

```
var wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(Driver.Value, new TimeSpan(0,0,60)).Until(OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
Driver.Value.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();
```

And this

```
Driver.Value.SwitchTo().Alert().SetAuthenticationCredentials("test", "test");
```

and this

```
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Driver.Value.SwitchTo().Alert().SetAuthenticationCredentials("test", "test");
                break; //this is brute force I know
            }
            catch 
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
```

No luck, they all throw a "no alert found" exception. We would switch to firefox, but it is an internal application and we only support IE or Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to use the authentication options inside Selenium with the basic authtication prompt. Instead I found that if you run fiddler in the background, you can have it auto-authenticate for you when prompted based on a specific site. Then the popup never shows up and your Selenium scripts run just fine.

[Auto http authenticate traffic for a specific site with fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680885/auto-http-authenticate-traffic-for-a-specific-site-with-fiddler)